# Apply Styling automatically after upload

Tags: jquery, css, html, file-upload

Can someone point me in the right direction. I have a web page using jquery and fancybox,whereby images are displayed in fancy polaroid style, etc etc.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grundysf/paF9N/8/)

How can I make so that a new photo/s added/uploaded using html5 file APi, will place itself into the div and apply the necessary styling. below is the div I would need the image added to.  So if I upload a 100 pictures they would all have the same styling automatically after upload. Thanks

```
<div id="view3">
   <div id="polaroid"> <!--class for styling-->
<!--Image One-->
    <figure><a class="fancybox" title="Image-1" href="images/1.png"><img src="images/1.png" width="250" height="200" alt="" /></a> <!--the image-->
<textarea>Image-1</textarea> <!--the caption that appears below the image-->
</figure>
```

Comment: code is working fine  what is that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a handler for your uploads and just wanna know how to add your files? In that case you can do something like this:

```
var parent = $("#polaroid"), 
img =  "<figure><a class='fancybox' title='Image-1' href='images/" + yourFile + "'><img   src='" + yourFile + "' width='250' height='200' alt='' /></a>";
parent.append(img);
```

Comment: awesome, yes im using html5 event handler. `<input type="file" id="file"/>`  I'm assuming I would need more than the javascript and the vent handler, how is the image actually put onto the canvas?